# Do you share your grumble about company stuff you don't agree upon with people who report to you?

Tags: management, people-management, complaint

[“Gripes go up, not down.”](https://petracoach.com/complain-maintain-effective-management-andy-bailey/)

Say you got a task from your boss and feel awkward with it.

You state to the boss you are uneasy with the task, but still, he asks you to do it.

Then you take it to your people.

And they also gripe about it.

At that point, do you say "I agree with you, I also don't like it, but this is what we need to do" or will you hide what you really think about the task?

Feels a bit hypocritical to say nothing about your real feelings when people who report to you share the same thought.

Comment: Did you mean to say something like "dishonest" instead of "hypocritical"? I wouldn't agree that it's dishonest either but I can see how you might think it's a lie by omission. Hypocritical doesn't make sense here.

Comment: Sharing how you feel is different from grumbling.

Comment: There's a huge difference between sharing an opinion about a decision you disagree with and complaining/griping/grumbling about it.

Answer (score 15):

> At that point, do you say "I agree with you, I also don't like it, but
> this is what we need to do" or will you hide what you really think
> about the task?
>
> Feels a bit hypocritical to say nothing about your real feelings when
> people who report to you share the same thought.

This might depend on the culture of the company and/or your boss.

Ask yourself, "What would my boss tell me to do, if I asked this question of them?". And if you don't already know the answer, discuss it with them.

I've had some bosses who told me specifically that I am not to share my actual feelings with my team in this context. I was told that my job was to be on the "side" of management, to convey the directive, and to get the job done.

But most bosses left that decision to me. In that case, I would typically share my feelings about the directive, hear my team's grumbles, but explain why it was necessary to do it anyway.

I prefer to be very open and honest with my team as much as I can. That option wasn't always available to me. Sometimes, when I can't be open enough, that's incentive enough for me to find a new job.

Answer (score 9):

I believe as a responsible, open supervisor/team lead it is a requirement for the people under you to at least understand the reasoning behind the tasks given.

If the reasoning is one of, “well i discussed this with my superiors and they want this done, regardless of my disagreement” and this is something that just simply cannot be changed through intelligent discussion, I would inform those under me my understanding of why the task is being done the way it is and we just have to do it, but this depends on the nature of the task. I would expect my manager to also be open to me and not be hiding information relevant to doing my job correctly and me being my best.

I would not however go on some tirade about how dumb I think management is and that we’re wasting time but well that’s business, just do what you’re told. As that would make myself look petty that I’m not getting what I want and depending on the relationship between yourself and the underlings, it may influence them negatively to a point of demotivation and team disillusion. But this is also a question of frequency.

I suppose any person would have a hard time trying to legitimize incompetent decisions from above *always* when everyone in is agreement that the task is being done wrong/will cause problems later.

To recap I think it’s fine to sympathize with the people under you. But it should be in a constructive, informative manner that encourages the employee to do their best and that their objection will also be noted the next time a similar decision from above comes around, which will hopefully help to change the mind of said managers, but sympathy shouldn’t morph into whining as it rarely gets anything anywhere.

Comment: +1 for sympathize, else it become a one-way route, the team may not feel "listened" then the team become distant, disconnected, with the leader.

Comment: +1 trust is a horrible thing to lose. As a previous company stated "yea, there are tasks that ... are not cool. But required for the business. Our solution: take turns instead of dumping them on someone in particular."

Answer (score 1):

Grumbling for grumbling's sake doesn't do anything useful regardless in which direction it's happening.

An open conversation of what needs to happen and why can help generate better understanding, acceptance and buy-in from the team.

Of course, that depends a lot on what your chain of management has given you to work with. The better the rationale is that go got, the better the rationale you can give to your team.

It's always ok to "disagree and commit". You or anyone on your team can openly state that they are not happy with the decision, but then it's time move on and get to work on it anyway. Ultimately only the decision maker is accountable for the decision. Only time can tell what the best option would have been.

Answer (score 1):

The answer may be dependant on your work culture, your country and your company culture.

As a manager, part of our job is to convey our company's opinion to the people who report to us. This includes sharing the company's POV and arguments even if we disagree with it. Sharing our grumble about company stuff is incompatible with this.

If you're not confortable with this situation (or with the POV you're supposed to share), consider changing to another company that would be more aligned with your POV.

---

In short: if you are a manager, you have to own your company's decision, arguments and POV to your managees and this is incompatible with letting them know you disagree.

Comment: I disagree. The problem is rarely-to-never that the executive opinion has been insufficiently communicated. People at the lower rungs always know in some detail what the executives think about the work. What is often a problem is that the executives don't know what the people doing the work actually think.